# Jumping to a new anchor on dynamic web pages where anchor not yet available

Tags: jquery, anchor

**Senario.**

I have an active website with people posting lots of comments. I have a recent comments box that contains a summary of the last 10 comments linked with a URL to the full comment. 
When the summary comment in the Recent Comments box is clicked,

1. if the comment is on a different page, the new page loads and the web page jumps to the anchor;
2. if the comment is on the same page as the user then the webpage jumps to the anchor.

**Problem**

I have changed the recent comments to refresh every minute. However, the actual comments on the page do not refresh (just the summary comments in the recent comments box. I now have three scenarios.

When the summary comment in the Recent Comments box is clicked,

1. if the comment is on a different page, the new page loads and the web page jumps to the anchor;
2. if the comment is on the same page as the user and the comment already displayed on the page then the webpage jumps to the anchor;
3. if the comment is in the recent comments box, and should be on the same page as the user but is not yet shown because the comment was created after the page was loaded then nothing happens.

If the anchor exists on the page then it will be within the div "comments-area". I cannot just look to see if the anchor exists anywhere on the page - because it exist as a URL in the recent comments box!

**Ideal Outcome**

I would like the page to reload and jump to the anchor for outcome number 3.

**Please help me with this code**

I have written the following script to try to make it work

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.bwp-rc-textlink', function() {
    var tourl = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    if ( tourl.contains(window.location.pathname)) 
    {
        var tohash = tourl.substring(tourl.indexOf("#")+1);
        if( jQuery('comments-area').find('a[href='+tourl+']').length )
        {
            window.location.href = tourl;
        }
        else
        {
            window.location.assign(tourl);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        window.location.href = tourl;
    }
});
```

but it is not working.

The line that is failing is the line that checks for the URL in the "comments-area" div. This line if( jQuery('comments-area').find('a[href='+tourl+']').length

What have I done wrong? All help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this is a daft question, why don't you reload the comments at the same time, wouldn't that be the best solution?

Comment: I agree, but reloading the comments at the same time is more CPU intensive and it would overload my server.

Comment: I doubt that it'd overload your server...

Comment: It would cause my page response times to be too slow, so is not the answer I am looking for. Thanks for the suggestion thou'.

Comment: No it wouldn't. AJAX is **asynchronous**... You'd only poll `x` seconds, and then pass back JSON...

Comment: Sorry Ben, refreshing the comments at the same time is a non-starter for me. I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: Would this work?
   
   jQuery(document).on('click', '.bwp-rc-textlink', function() {

  var tourl = jQuery(this).attr('href');

  if ( tourl.contains(window.location.pathname)) 
  {
   if( jQuery('.comment-meta a').attr('href',tourl).length )
   {
    window.location.href = tourl;
   }
   else
   {
    window.location.assign(tourl);
   }
  }
  else
  {
   window.location.href = tourl;
  }
 });

Comment: The above answer worked. If someone can vote it up please?